# I want to add a Jquery popup on click of post comment button

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup, comments

I want to add a Jquery popup on click of post comment button and data of that  form is saved only when submit button on form is clicked. this is what i have worked till now

http://trueblueseo.com/seo/?p=23

but i not able to assign a j query popup on post event

Comment: when the comment button is clicked a pop up will be there and then in poup there will be 2 fields with a submit button and only when submit button is clicked the comment should be inserted in databse

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function pop_on_click(){

    use jquery and ajax here to get value of text and post it & later you can store it in database ....
}
</script>

<?php add_thickbox(); ?>
<div id="my-content-id" style="display:none;">
     <p>
          Do you want to post this comment ? 

    <input type="submit" name="confirm_comment" id="confirm_comment" onclick="pop_on_click(); return false;" class="confirm_comment" />

     </p>
</div>
<input type="text" name="text_comment" id="text_comment" class="text_comment" />

<a href="#TB_inline?width=200&height=150&inlineId=my-content-id" class="thickbox">Post Comment</a>
```